# What is REST API to start Cloudera Management Service?

Tags: rest, cluster-computing, cloudera-manager

I can start the cluster using REST API of Cloudera Manager below:

curl -X POST -u "admin:admin" "http://""n0001:7180""/api/v6/clusters/Cluster_1/commands/start"

And this is the figure out of the Cloudera Manager after I run the REST API.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f4Cn.png)

But the **Cloudera Management Service still is not running**. What is **the REST API** to start the **Cloudera Management Service**?

Note: I want to start the Cluster and Cloudera Management Service using REST API CM. Not by Cloudera Manager UI.

Answer (score 1):

**To Start it:**

```
/api/v11/cm/service/commands/start
```

**To stop it:**

```
/api/v11/cm/service/commands/stop
```

See: [Cloudera's Api Documentation](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v11/path__cm_service_commands_start.html)